# Get array element after performing a function on it?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, function

I'm looking to see if there is some PHP syntax that I'm missing that will allow me to grab the contents of the array I just manipulated using a function..

Good example:

```
$firstElement = sort($myArray)[0];
```

Where normally I would have to do this:

```
$myArray = sort($myArray);
$firstElement = $myArray[0];
```

Any clean way of doing this??

Thanks Everyone!
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no syntax to access an array value if it’s not in a variable. There was a [proposal to add such a syntax](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) but it was declined.

PS: [`sort`](http://docs.php.net/sort) does only return boolean values. So your example wouldn’t work anyway.

Comment: Ah ok. Well I had different code - but I thought it might make more sense to show sort :-/. Ha guess not.

Answer (score 2):

A syntax like this one

$firstElement = sort($myArray)[0];

is definitly nont possible -- you have noticed that yourself ^^

If you are willing to get the **first** element of an array, you could use the [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) function, like this :

```
$list = array('z', 'c', 'd');
$element = reset($list);
var_dump($element);
```

It would display :

```
string 'z' (length=1)
```

The side-effect is that (quote) :

> reset() rewinds array 's internal
>   pointer to the first element and
>   returns the value of the first array
>   element.

Btw, as sort doesn't return the array, you cannont do that :

```
$list = array('z', 'c', 'd');
$element = reset(sort($list));
var_dump($element);
```

It would give a warning :

> Warning: reset() [function.reset]:
>   Passed variable is not an array or
>   object

Comment: Ah yah. I wanted an example that was easy to understand but it looks like I messed that one up :-/. Yah that's a little more confusing and verbose than my alternative method. I was just wondering if I missed something along my PHP journey that would make it quicker! Thanks though!

Comment: Well, the solution you proposed in your question is the one I actually always use ^^ But was fun to think about another one anyway ^^